# Construct independent $X_n$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty Var(X_n)=\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, random-variables

How to construct an independent random variable $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n$ converges and $\mathrm{Var}(X_n)$ is uniformly bounded by some constant C, but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathrm{Var}(X_n)=\infty$.

We have learnt that instead of assuming that  $\mathrm{Var}(X_n)$ is uniformly bounded by some constant $C$, we assume $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly bounded by some constant $C$. Then
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathrm{Var}(X_n)<\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Let $X_n$ equal $0$ with probability $1-1/n^2$, and otherwise be very large. Argue using Borel-Cantelli that $\sum_n X_n$ converges almost surely. On the other hand, you can arrange that $\mathrm{Var} X_n = 1$, say. Note that the $X_n$ would *not* be uniformly bounded.

Comment: Thank. By the way, how to ensure $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is independent?

Comment: Why wouldn't they be independent? You can define them however you want.

Comment: If $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is defined on probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$, can you give a specific probability space such that for any finite set $J$, $A_i\in \mathbb{R}, i\in J$ , then $\mathbb{P}(X_i\in A_i, i\in J)=\prod_{i\in J}\mathbb{P}(X_j\in A_j)$

Comment: If you have an infinite sequence of independent uniform $U(0,1)$ variables, i.e. $\Omega = [0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ with the proper $\mathcal{\cF}$, then you can implement my probability space. It's the same thing you need to do when you consider infinitely many coin tosses.

Comment: Yes. I just read a theorem about how to construct a sequence of independent random variables. It's the way you presented. Thanks.